# Python module not found despite running pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I have a bash script (start.sh) like this:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
python api/api.py
```

...with a requirements.txt file that reads:

```
flask
flask_restful
transformers
tensorflow
flask_cors
```

But when I run:

```
bash start.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
from flask import Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Shouldn't this have been installed from my requirements.txt file?

Comment: Are you running the correct `pip` for the `python` you are running? Try `python -m pip` instead

Comment: @IainShelvington I tried with `-m` as well but get the same error.

Comment: Maybe you need to execute `pip3 install Flask` if you have `python`

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your problem and I got it working with

```sh
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
python3 api/api.py
```